# How to publish a single page of a web page solution using Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

This is hard to describe but I'll try this...

Let's say I am working on a multiple page web solution and make a small change to one web page.  The small change needs to get published but I want to be able to publish it without having to republish the entire site.  How do i do that? How do i publish a single page of a multi-page solution in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 0):

Simply FTP the ASPX page to the server, along with any other static files such as images, CSS or JavaScript that the page uses. If there is code involved, you will have to rebuild the solution and deploy the DLL file also.

Comment: How would he know which DLL file it is? I've got the same issue (albeit with VS2008) and all of my DLLs in /bin have filenames that appear to bear no relation to the pages of my site. Also, there are far fewer DLLs than there are pages. (Can you tell I'm new to ASP.NET and trying to maintain a pre-existing site?)

Comment: He didn't specify whether it was a Web Application Project or a Website Project, so it depends...